# ngFor counting without any array or object, and how to use ngFor again within a ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

> I want to show count from 0 to user -> term.
>   How can I add this count digits into a dropdown
>
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-djze7u
>   Please check this editorial link
>
> Home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content *ngFor="let item of users">

     //Here Already I have added a *ngfor so how can i solve this ?

      <ion-row>
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}:</ion-label>
        <ion-label>{{item.age}}</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="count">
          <ion-option value="0" selected>0</ion-option>
```

> //Here dropdown will show from 0 to item.term

```
          <ion-option ngfor="let i=1 | i<item.term;" value="{{i}}" >{{i}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

> Home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  users:any = [
    { name: 'Composite Factory', age: 1, term:2 },
    { name: 'Todd', age: 2, term:1 },
    { name: 'Lisa', age: 3, term:4 }
  ];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by show count digits?

Comment: check users variable from home.ts, find the term, I want to show dropdown list from 0 to this term.

Comment: Please check edit link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-djze7u and edit here